# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for <Component>, but the same service works just fine in other components?

Tags: angular

This is my service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostService {
  name:string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private location: Location,
    private router: Router
    ) { }

  public openPostItDialog(dialog: MatDialog): void {
    const dialogRef = dialog.open(PostItDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { name: this.name }
    });
    const url = this.router.createUrlTree(['post']).toString();
    this.location.go(url);
    console.log("Dialog was open");

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log("The dialog was closed");
      this.name = result;
      this.location.go("");
    })
  }

  // Async Calls
  public fetchPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get<Post[]>('api/v1/posts');
  }

  public createNewPost(form: FormGroup){
    console.log(form);
  }
}
```

it is provided in the app.module

In this component's constructor, the PostService cannot be resolved?

```
export class PostItDialog implements OnInit {
  public postForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PostItDialog>,    
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: PostItDialogData,
    private postService: PostService
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.postForm = new FormGroup({
      'feed': new FormGroup({
        'title': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100), Validators.minLength(4)]),
        'description': new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
      }),
      'movie': new FormGroup({
        'title': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50), Validators.minLength(3)]),
      })
    })
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.postForm);
    this.postForm.reset();
    this.postService.createNewPost(this.postForm)
  }

  onNoClick(): void{    
    this.dialogRef.close();
    this.postForm.reset();
  }

}
```

I have no idea why. Injecting this same service elsewhere works just fine. I can remove the PostService object from the constructor and it works just fine. Its only this component PostItDialog that cannot resolve PostService. Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Regarding this `it is provided in the app.module` ... if you are using `providedIn` as shown in your code above, it should **not** also be provided in your module.

Comment: ok, I thought that it was saying that its provided in root and I had to provide it in the root app.module. Ill remove it right now. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It is saying that *it* is providing it in the root application injector, so you don't have to do anything more. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just realized who you were. I really enjoyed watching your Pluralsight C# tutorials haha!

Comment: Thanks! And looking further at your component, I'd guess that the error is due to your component's constructor. You can only define parameters that can be injected in via Angular's injector ... so only services. I think your first parameter may be causing the problem.

Comment: Surprisingly, everything works just fine with dialogRef and data. They are required for the angular material dialog to work. Its always complaining about the PostService. I removed it and it worked just fine. I created a new PostItDialogService and it works just fine. I have a feeling its something with how I am importing my modules. But I thought angular just merges the module imports into one list of available services.

Comment: I see. I lean "anti-modal", so I'm not familiar with the material modal dialog.Hopefully someone else with modal experience can jump in and provide some insight.

Comment: The thing is that even if I were to remove the dialogRef and DATA that are specific to the modal, and treated the component as if it were NOT a modal, the issue would still occurs. But Thank you

Comment: What happens if you take "location" out of the PostService?

Comment: I took out Location from PostService, and the PostItDialog component is still complaining about the same issue. That the last object in the constructor cannot be resolved. That last object in the ctor for PostItDialog component is PostService.

Comment: Yea, that was why I was wondering if the problem was in the PostService itself ... if one it *its* constructor parameters were causing the problem with it being used in another component's constructor. What I would suggest at this point is to do a very simple mock-up of your issue using Stackblitz so we can all take a look.

Comment: Ok I will see if I can reproduce it really quickly.